# How to check if a TypeMirror returnType of a method is an enum

Tags: java

I am writing a annotation processor. My annotation is applied to methods inside an interface:

```
public interface Sample {
   @MyAnnotation
   public ReturnEnum method();
}
```

ReturnEnum is a enum written by myself.
In my processor code I do something like this:

```
TypeMirror returnType = methodElement.getReturnType();
```

I can get the name of my return type: *my.package.ReturnEnum*
But I don't know, if I can check it is a enum type.
Is there a way?

greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Find a solution. Seems like you just have to cast it to a specific TypeElement.

```
public void myMethod(ExecutableElement methodElement) {
   TypeMirror typeMirror = methodElement.getReturnType();
   if (typeMirror.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED) {
      TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) ((DeclaredType) type).asElement();
      if (typeElement.getKind() == ElementKind.ENUM) {
         // I wanted to get here...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure I understand your question.

But you can use if statements or even better switch statements to compare values.

Comment: if the question is not clear, please, add comments to clarify